# Questions related to the Riemann zeta function where $|\zeta(s)|=|\zeta(1-s)|$

Tags: number-theory, riemann-zeta, riemann-hypothesis

The Riemann Zeta functional equation is defined as follows.

---

**(1)** $\quad\zeta (s)=f(s)\,\zeta(1-s)\,,\quad f(s)=2^s\pi^{s-1}\sin\left(\frac{\pi\,s}{2}\right)\,\Gamma (1-s)$

---

Note that $|f(s)|=1$ along the critical line where $s=\frac{1}{2}+i\,t$, but I've been investigating other values of $s$ for which $|f(s)|=1$ which is equivalent to $|\zeta(s)|=|\zeta(1-s)|$.

---

The following figure illustrates a contour plot of $|\zeta(s)|=|\zeta(1-s)|$ where the horizontal axis represents $\Re(s)$ and the vertical axis represents $\Im(s)$. Note there's a closed path which is symmetric about the critical line and real axis where $|\zeta(s)|=|\zeta(1-s)|$. The two red dots at the intersections of the closed path and the critical line are at $s=\frac{1}{2}+i\,6.28984$ and $s=\frac{1}{2}-i\,6.28984$.

---

[image: Contour Plot of |\zeta(s)|=|\zeta(1-s)|]

**Figure (1)**: Contour Plot of $|\zeta(s)|=|\zeta(1-s)|$

---

**Question (1)**: Can the value $6.28984$ be expressed as a function of mathematical constants?

---

Since I originally posted question (1) above, I've noticed that $\pm 6.28984$ is associated with the location of the minima and maxima of the Riemann-Siegel theta function.

---

The following table illustrates points along the closed path illustrated in Figure (1) where $\Re(s)\in\mathbb{Z}$.

---

**Table (1)**: $\quad\begin{array}{ccc}
 \Re(s) & \Im(s) & \text{} \\
 -16 & -0.511623 & 0.511623 \\
 -15 & -0.945774 & 0.945774 \\
 -14 & -1.5719 & 1.5719 \\
 -13 & -2.12883 & 2.12883 \\
 -12 & -2.66579 & 2.66579 \\
 -11 & -3.17309 & 3.17309 \\
 -10 & -3.6505 & 3.6505 \\
 -9 & -4.09581 & 4.09581 \\
 -8 & -4.50702 & 4.50702 \\
 -7 & -4.88189 & 4.88189 \\
 -6 & -5.21802 & 5.21802 \\
 -5 & -5.51293 & 5.51293 \\
 -4 & -5.76403 & 5.76403 \\
 -3 & -5.96879 & 5.96879 \\
 -2 & -6.12484 & 6.12484 \\
 -1 & -6.23013 & 6.23013 \\
 0 & -6.28319 & 6.28319 \\
 1 & -6.28319 & 6.28319 \\
 2 & -6.23013 & 6.23013 \\
 3 & -6.12484 & 6.12484 \\
 4 & -5.96879 & 5.96879 \\
 5 & -5.76403 & 5.76403 \\
 6 & -5.51293 & 5.51293 \\
 7 & -5.21802 & 5.21802 \\
 8 & -4.88189 & 4.88189 \\
 9 & -4.50702 & 4.50702 \\
 10 & -4.09581 & 4.09581 \\
 11 & -3.6505 & 3.6505 \\
 12 & -3.17309 & 3.17309 \\
 13 & -2.66579 & 2.66579 \\
 14 & -2.12883 & 2.12883 \\
 15 & -1.5719 & 1.5719 \\
 16 & -0.945774 & 0.945774 \\
 17 & -0.511623 & 0.511623 \\
\end{array}$

---

The following table illustrates points along the closed path illustrated in Figure (1) where $\Im(s)\in\mathbb{Z}$.

---

**Table (2)**: $\quad\begin{array}{ccc}
 \Im(s) & \Re(s) & \text{} \\
 -6 & -2.82313 & 3.82313 \\
 -5 & -6.66187 & 7.66187 \\
 -4 & -9.22159 & 10.2216 \\
 -3 & -11.3476 & 12.3476 \\
 -2 & -13.2329 & 14.2329 \\
 -1 & -14.9193 & 15.9193 \\
 0 & -16.4061 & 17.4061 \\
 1 & -14.9193 & 15.9193 \\
 2 & -13.2329 & 14.2329 \\
 3 & -11.3476 & 12.3476 \\
 4 & -9.22159 & 10.2216 \\
 5 & -6.66187 & 7.66187 \\
 6 & -2.82313 & 3.82313 \\
\end{array}$

---

**Question (2)**: Can any of the $\Im(s)$ values in Table (1) or any of the $\Re(s)$ values in Table (2) be expressed as functions of mathematical constants?

---

**Question (3)**: What is the length and area of the closed path illustrated in Figure (1)?

---

**Question (4)**: Assuming $s$ is on the closed path illustrated in Figure (1), can $\Im(s)$ be written as a function of $\Re(s)$ or vice-versa?

---

**Question (5)**: Would a proof that there is no point $s$ in the critical strip where $|f(s)|=1$, $\Re(s)\ne\frac{1}{2}$, and $\Im(s)>c$ for some $c\in\mathbb{R}$ constitute a proof of the Riemann hypothesis, or has it been shown that for any value of $c\in\mathbb{R}$ there is a point $s$ in the critical strip where $|f(s)|=1$, $\Re(s)\ne\frac{1}{2}$, and $\Im(s)>c$ for which $\zeta(1-s)$ is not a zero of the Riemann zeta function?

---

I've noticed successive derivatives of the Riemann zeta function $\zeta(s)$ also seem to exhibit analogous results. The following figure illustrates contour plots of $|\zeta^{(n)}(s)|=|\zeta^{(n)}(1-s)|$ for $n=0$, $n=1$, $n=2$, and $n=3$ in blue, orange, green, and red respectively where the horizontal axis represents $\Re(s)$ and the vertical axis represents $\Im(s)$.

---

[image: Contour Plots of |\zeta^{(n)}(s)|=|\zeta^{(n)}(1-s)|]

**Figure (2)**: Contour Plots of $|\zeta^{(n)}(s)|=|\zeta^{(n)}(1-s)|$

---

I believe there's a single closed contour where $|\zeta(s)|=|\zeta(1-s)|$ associated with the first trivial zeta zero, and a pair of closed contours where $|\zeta(s)|=|\zeta(1-s)|$ associated with each subsequent trivial zeta zero. I believe in many cases (if not all) there are analogous closed contours associated with $|\zeta^{(n)}(s)|=|\zeta^{(n)}(1-s)|$.

Comment: $\log f(s)$ has a simple explicit formula and the curves where $\Re(f(s)) = 0$ are close to those obtained from the Stirling approximation. The functional equation just says that $\theta(s) =\Gamma((s+1/2)/2) \pi^{-(s+1/2)/2} \zeta(s+1/2)$  is even, you can't deduce anything about the RH from that (the basic properties of $\theta(s)$ tell us the density of zeros)

Comment: Why don't you plot $\Re(f(s))$ and its Stirling approximation

Comment: @reuns Originally my primary motivation for this question was a desire to clarify question (4) and it's answer in my mind which you addressed in your first comment above. The closed paths where $|\zeta^{(n)}(s)|=|\zeta^{(n)}(1-s)|$ were initially somewhat of a curiosity to me, but I think I now understand the source of these closed paths. I've haven't yet taken the time to look into the Stirling approximation which I've seen mentioned a number of times, but I suppose it's about time I did.

Comment: In my previous comment I meant question 5 instead of question 4.